# What are the maximal $p$-subgroups of $A_5$?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I need to find the Sylow $p$-subgroups of the alternating group $A_5.$
So I need to find the maximal $p$-subgroups of $A_5.$

First of all, what are the elements of $A_5$? I know they are the even permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ but what does this mean?

Apparently $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z= \left<(1,2,3)\right> $ is a Sylow $3$- subgroup of $A_5.$ Why is this?

Comment: The even permutations are the ones that have sign equal to 1, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation. That subgroup is a sylow subgroup of $A_5$ cause $|A_5|=60=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ and that group has size 3 (the largest power of 3 dividing $|A_5|$).

Comment: I don't seem to understand, I thought Z/3Z is the set of elements of Z mod 3 so (1,2,3), what has this got to do with the alternating group? How is this a subgroup of the alternating group?

Comment: The subgroup $\left < (1, 2, 3) \right>$ is a cyclic group of order $3,$ generated by the element $(1, 2, 3).$ Any cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z.$ Fixing an isomorphism between $\left < (1, 2, 3) \right>$ and $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ we can consider $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup of $A_5.$

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1612294/173147

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of defining the sign $sgn:S_n\to \{-1,1\}$ of a permutation. The key property of $sgn$ is that $sgn(\sigma)=-1$ if $\sigma$ is a transposition, that is, a permutation that exchanges two elements. $A_n$ is defined to be the kernel of $sgn$,i.e. is set of permutations which have sign 1 (also called even permutations). A sylow p-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is a subgroup $H$ such that $|H|=$ the largest power of p dividing $|G|$. Since $S_5=120$ we have $A_5=60=2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5$. $Z/3Z$ isn't exactly $<(1,2,3)>$ but is isomorphic to that subgroup since both are cyclic of order $3$, so $Z/3Z$ is isomorphic to a sylow 3-subgroup of $A_5$.